# Conditional projection with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a query over a single entity (with some navigation properties) and need to project them into a model for consumption by API clients.  It looks basically like this:

```
repository.CreateQuery<Reviews>()
  .Where(/* criteria */)
  .Select(m => new
    {
      ID = m.ID,
      Reviewers = m.IsAnonymous 
        ? m.Reviewers.Take(1).Select(r => new { Name = "Anonymous" })
        : m.Reviewers.Select(r => new { Name = r.Name })
    })
```

LINQ to Entities fails to execute this at runtime.  In the Visual Studio debugger, the exception message is "Specified method is not supported".  In LinqPad, the inner exception is "The nested query is not supported.  Operation1='Case' Operations2='Collect'".

Any ideas how to work around this?  I'd rather not force the query to execute to get the objects in memory because the point of this conditional query is to solve a performance issue, so as far as I can tell I really need to solve this within the scope of the L2E query.

**Update**: the projected types aren't anonymous in my real application.  I just used anonymous ones here because it was convenient to contrive the example.  In similar fashion, the real queries involve a number of additional properties which mean a great deal more data coming from the mapped tables.

Comment: Why are you using `.Take(1).Select()` instead of just using `new { Name = "Anonymous" }`?

Comment: @Bobson because the result has to be an `IEnumerable`.  Unfortunately, LINQ-to-Entities is unable to cast the more obvious choices of array and List to IEnumerable (unless there's some trick I'm missing).  Also, if it helps, the anonymous types in my example above are all well-defined in my actual application.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this will work, but in this case can you select both as just a string ie `.Select(r => "Anonymous")` and `.Select(r => r.Name)` (so they are the same type) and then select into your annon object later in the query? I suppose the other option is not to use annon types here and to create an actual one so you get better type equality

Comment: @LukeMcGregor that would work, but it wouldn't solve my problem.  The solution to the performance issue is to not do the underlying query for anonymous reviewers, and if I just select string as you suggest, I would be retrieving quite a lot of data that will just be discarded.  Also, you may not have seen, but I added in a comment above that in my real application the projected types aren't anonymous.  I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Do the query twice, with an additional filter on `m.IsAnonymous`?  Then `.Concat()` the results.

Comment: @BenCollins hmm ok i see what you mean, I thought your issue was from type equality between the two annon types.

Comment: i suspect a let statement would work in a proper query syntax...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use union to do what you want:

```
var query1 = repository.CreateQuery<Reviews>()
                       .Where(/* criteria */);
var queryAnonimous = query1.Where(m=>m.IsAnonymous)
                           .Select(m => new
                                        {
                                            ID = m.ID,
                                            Reviewers = m.Reviewers.Take(1).Select(r => new { Name = "Anonymous" })        
                                        })

var queryNotAnonymous =  query1.Where(m=>!m.IsAnonymous)
                               .Select(m => new
                                            {
                                                ID = m.ID,
                                                Reviewers = m.Reviewers.Select(r => new { Name = r.Name })
                                            })
var unionQuery = queryAnonimous.union(queryNotAnonymous);
```